# How to recursively expand/resolve/flatten nested models in keras?

Tags: recursion, machine-learning, neural-network, nested, keras

Let's say I built a nested model like this:

```python
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers.core import Input, Dense

model_1 = Sequential()
model_1.add(Dense(...))
model_1.add(Dense(...))

input_2 = Input(...)
output_2 = Dense(...)(input_2)
model_2 = Model(inputs=input_2, outputs=output_2) 

model = Sequential()
model.add(model_1)
model.add(model_2)
```

How can I transform this recursively into a "flat" model, that does not contain any `Model` or `Sequential` layers.

Since `model_1` and `model_2` might have been trained in advance the parameters should be conserved during the transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and I got a working solution, but this doesn't seem very elegant.

The basic idea is to iterate through the layers of the sub-models and add them to the overall model one by one rather than adding the entire sub-models.

```
model = Sequential()

for layer1 in model1.layers:
    model.add(layer1)

for layer2 in model2.layers:
    model.add(layer2)
```

If the model already includes nested models, it is possible to iterate over them via:

```
model_flat = Sequential()

for layer_nested in model.get_layer('nested_model').layers:
    model_flat.add(layer_nested)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't check if it works but it seems like a valid solution. I also don't remember how exactly I was running into this problem, but I think I needed to the model to be "flat" in order to use https://github.com/dmlc/nnvm. (Which I ultimately didn't use because of this limitation)